# Linq-to-Sql many-to-many

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I have a many-to-many query problem in Linq-to-SQL.

I have a table named `user`.

`User` has got 2 products  >  join `product.UserID` 
and `Product` can be have 2 equipment. `Product` to `Equipments` have many to many association

I want to get user's equipments:

```
 var match =  from c in ctx.Products                              
    where c.UserID == USERID
    select c.Equipments;
```

This code returns `IQueryable<System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection<Equipments>>` typed object.

But I want to get `IQueryable<Equipments>` typed object. How can I cast?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sound like you want `SelectMany`.

```
var match =  from c in ctx.Products                              
    where c.UserID == USERID
    from e in c.Equipments
    select e;
```

`match` is `IQueryable<Equipments>` now